# Issue deploying Flask Rest Api on Nginx

Tags: nginx, python, socket, websocket, flask

I'm trying to deploy my flask api rest on nginx (on a subdomain) without success. I've followed [this example from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) and everything was working properly but then I changed the tutorial example code to my mine and POST requests aren't working at all. I'm using Postman Chrome App and each time I do a POST request to "api.domain.com/CreateUser" I get a 404 error:

"The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

This is my VH config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.domain.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/apirest/apirest.sock;
    }
}
```

And this is the python file (flask api sample):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, url_for, redirect, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app)

class CreateUser(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return jsonify({
            'status': 'ok', 
            'message': 'user successfuly created'
        })

api.add_resource(CreateUser, '/CreateUser')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Anyone has a clue about what's happening? Thanks so much!